# How to grant more permissions to android shell user?

Tags: android, shell, android-ndk, opensl

I build some command line tool with ndk and execute it in /data/local/tmp. Now it prompts me "requires android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" when I call some OpenSLES API in my command line tool:

```
W/AudioRecord( 4226): AUDIO_INPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
W/ServiceManager(  207): Permission failure: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO from uid=2000 pid=4226
E/        (  207): Request requires android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
D/PowerManagerService(  964): handleSandman: canDream=false, mWakefulness=Asleep
E/AudioFlinger(  207): openRecord() permission denied: recording not allowed
E/AudioRecord( 4226): AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
E/libOpenSLES( 4226): android_audioRecorder_realize(0x453430) error creating AudioRecord object
W/libOpenSLES( 4226): Leaving Object::Realize (SL_RESULT_CONTENT_UNSUPPORTED)
```

I have also tried to grant shell with pm grant:

```
pm grant "com.android.shell" android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
pm grant "com.android.shell" android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
pm grant "com.android.shell" android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.android.shell has not requested permission android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
```

changing /system/etc/permissions/platform.xml has no effect too.

Can I just debug my OpenSLES demo in the android shell ? How can I get more permisson just in shell .

Must I create a jni and java project for every experimental code snippet and modify them together when I change some C++ interfaces ?

Can I access RECORD_AUDIO, CAMERA directly in a command tool from shell ?

Comment: @Samveen Your have a post about running C++ application in android shell. Do you know how to grant permissions to C++ application ?

Comment: Yes, you can run it as superuser. You need a rooted device for that.

Answer (score 5):

This is the [new permissions model in Android Marshmallow](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) in action. To get this permission you'll need to prompt the user to grant it. Here's what I do:

1. Whenever I need RECORD_AUDIO permission I run a check to see if I have it:

   ```
   private boolean hasRecordAudioPermission(){
       boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

       log("Has RECORD_AUDIO permission? " + hasPermission);
       return hasPermission;
   }
   ```
2. If I don't have it then request it

   ```
   private void requestRecordAudioPermission(){

       String requiredPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;

       // If the user previously denied this permission then show a message explaining why
       // this permission is needed
       if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
               requiredPermission)) {

           showToast("This app needs to record audio through the microphone....");
       }

       // request the permission.
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
               new String[]{requiredPermission},
               PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                          String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

       // This method is called when the user responds to the permissions dialog
   }
   ```